# In swift ,I need to show “10月02日”but not "10月2日",how to transfer "2"to "02"?

Tags: ios, swift

In swift ,I need to show **`“10月02日”`**but not **`"10月2日"`**,how to transfer **`"2"to "02"`**?

Now ， i have wrote these codes,but it will show "2",but not "02":

```
var publishLastDate:NSDate = momentLast.created_on
println(publishLastDate)
componentsLast = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: publishLastDate)
  lastDay = componentsLast.day
  lastMonth = componentsLast.month
  lastYear = componentsLast.year
```

Comment: Maybe if you actually showed the code that formats the data someone could help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're grabbing the components and printing the string yourself. You can format it like so:

```
let string = String(format: "%02d月%02d日", lastMonth, lastDay)
```